# Likebox doens´t work in IE (even on Facebook Developers)

Tags: internet-explorer, facebook-likebox

I got a very weird situation here. I´m trying to generate the Likebox Code for a facebook fanpage via the generator on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

But if i try to use this URL: **http://www.facebook.com/chiron.ausbildung** for the likebox, the preview just disappears. It DOES work though in Firefox. 
I thought it was a bug with the "dot" but that´s not it, since e.g. *****www.facebook.com/Ausbildung.Studium.made.by.TRUMPF* works just fine.

You can just try that enter the "chiron.ausbildung" URL in the generator (using IE / Chrome)

Any help?

Comment: have you solved your problem? I'm facing this same issue. Just on IE i can't see the like box or the like button of a specific page

Comment: Sorry unfortunately i have not